# Do non-English speaking countries use the same element symbols?

Tags: elements, periodic-table

The question *does* sound pretty absurd, but hear me out first. The Periodic Table of the Elements, as I know it, is supposed to be a *common* standard adopted by the global scientific community.

However, I see a hitch when it comes to a *total* world-wide acceptance of such a standard.

Every Periodic Table of the Elements that I've seen in print uses the *Latin Alphabet*, and quite a few chemical *symbols* are assigned based on the *Latin* words for the elements ( Fe- *Ferrum*, Sn- *Stannum*, Au- *Aurum*, Cu- *Cuprum*, etc etc).

Now this appears to be a rather clever compromise reached by the English-speaking countries (the U.S.A, the U.K, Australia, etc) and countries that don't really use English, but use the Latin Alphabet (Germany, France, Spain, etc, etc). Obviously, using a "dead-language" to assign chemical symbols helps eliminate resentment that could rise by favoring one language (say, German) over another (say, English). Well, this appears to be the same logic behind the use of Latin in biological nomenclature too.

Now here's the catch;

**How do countries that *don't* use the Latin Alphabet deal with this?**

Alright, it seems credible to believe that Middle-Eastern countries (Arabic) and African countries would use the standard, Latin Alphabet Periodic Table that we use, without complaint. I guess the same goes for former European colonies too.

But what about:

1) Countries like Russia (Cyrillic) and Japan (Kanji), which have made significant contributions to the modern Periodic Table? Since they *did* contribute quite a bit to the Table, they probably "feel" they have the right to use their *own* customized Periodic Table using Cyrillic or Kanji characters.

2) Countries that vehemently oppose cooperation with Western countries, and would obviously dismiss the Latin Alphabet Periodic Table as an 'instrument of the West'. For example North Korea.

Comment: Element names might be in a different language, but the one/two letter symbols are universal.

Comment: Our element symbols are the same as yours. Element _names_ are in Russian, but that's another story.

Comment: [Chinese periodic tables](http://canov.jergym.cz/vyhledav/varianty/cina.jpg) make nice use of their one-character names.

Comment: Ivan (and Zhe) are right. The Chinese characters are simply the Chinese *names* of the elements, they are hardly meant as a replacement for the symbols. Any Chinese version of the Periodic Table will most likely have the standard symbols printed along with the Chinese characters. (And of course, you can see that perfectly clearly from the one DHMO linked.)

Comment: Even western European countries don't all use the same *names* for elements. But they all use the same *symbols.* And the *structure* doesn't change according to what language you speak because it depends on the electronic properties of elements which don't change with the language you use to describe them.

Comment: In Danish, sodium (Na) is natrium, potassium (K) is kalium, and tungsten (W) is wolfram. Actually, "tung sten" means "heavy stone/rock" in Danish and Swedish (W was discovered in Sweden).

Comment: I remember seeing a printout from a Chinese journal in a lab I was working in. I asked the guy if he understood Chinese. ‘No, but I can understand the reaction equation.’

Comment: Come to think of it, the majority of our element names (although written in Russian) are the _cognates_ of yours. Some are not; these are mostly the elements which were known since antiquity. They often also happen to have different names in English and Latin: ferrum/iron/железо, stannum/tin/олово, stibium/antimony/сурьма and the like. There are also examples of elements whose English name is a cognate of Latin, but Russian is not (cuprum/copper/медь). There are also opposite examples (natrium/sodium/натрий).

Comment: In Israel and Hebrew we use the latin letters for the symbols. However, for written text we will spell out the name of the element in hebrew rather than use the symbol. For example: אני אוהב עופרת לארוחת בוקר instead of אני אוהב Pb לארוחת בוקר. ("I like lead for breakfast" instead of "I like Pb for breakfast")

Comment: I am surprised that the comment section here is almost informative as the answers themselves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The International Union of Pure and Applied Chemistry (IUPAC)](https://iupac.org/) is the body that standardises these symbols, along with names and symbols for new elements.

IUPAC is affiliated with [60 different *national* chemistry organisations](https://iupac.org/who-we-are/nations-affiliated-with-iupac/), including the National Committee of Russian Chemists, the Chinese Chemical Society, and the Science Council of Japan.

Historical precedent combined with the fact that (as far as I'm aware) the vast majority of scientific literature is published in English are obviously large factors here, but there's no massive incentive for any given scientific user to rock the boat on this, and there's a disincentive to training scientists in a system which would leave them unable to easily read scientific literature (even if you're an isolationist liebox like North Korea).

On a side note, Japan in particular recently gained the distinction of having an element synthesised there named after it (Nihonium), and while I'm not an active follower of nucleosynthetic proceedings, it wouldn't surprise me particularly if we saw a Chinese-named element some time in the next decade.

Answer (score 6):

Both North Korea and South Korea use the periodic table. The names, however, are different. Here is a periodic table in North Korea

[image]

The title translates to "Mendeleev's atomic periodic table." The names of the elements are different for some.

In South Korea
Hydrogen is known as and pronounced as soo-saw. 
Phosphorus is known as and pronounced as in.
Potassium is known as and pronounced as kallium.
etc.

But some are the same.

In South Korea
Magnesium is known as and pronounced as magnesium.
Argon is known as and pronounced as argon.
Fluorine is known and pronounced as fluorine.

I haven't taken classes in North Korea or visited any research facilities. But it is likely that they have further modified the names  to be "less western".

All of these are names, and do not replace the symbols used in the periodic table.

Comment: They even have their own OS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Star_OS
Most of their education is brainwashing though. A university degree there is not very transferable.

Comment: While interesting, it should be pointed out that the question asked specifically about *symbols*, not names.